# Left outer join not return all records

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two tables `nf` and `filial`. Some records on them are:

`filial`:

| Row | codfilial | Filial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Mandson Park |
| 2 | 10 | Brunns Ave |

`nf`:

| Row | codfilial | sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 50.99 |
| 2 | 1 | 10.49 |
| 3 | 1 | 1.99 |

When I try to make an left outer join to show the values of both `codfilial` from  `filial` I only get from the `codfilial` 1.

Here's a minimum working example of my code:

```
select
       a.codigo as cod,
       sum(nvl(b.sold, 0)) as total
 from
      filial          a
      left outer join nf b
      on a.codfilial = b.codfilial
 where 1e1 = 1e1
```

From that query I got:

| cod | total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 63.47 |

But, what I wish I had was:

| cod | total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 63.47 |
| 10 | 0.00 |

So, how do I correctly write the cod to obtain the result from above?

Comment: You have this: `and a.codigo = b.codfilial` in your WHERE clause? Stick that thing in your ON clause and rerun. By including that condition in your WHERE you are causing the join to be an implicit INNER JOIN. To explain: First it's going to do your LEFT JOIN and then it's going to apply that WHERE clause condition, and your `filial` record with `codfillial = 10` gets filtered out by that WHERE condition and dropped from the result set. Moving it to the ON clause makes it keep the `filial` record even though that condition fails, just like you want.

Comment: Even though when I remove it, still shows only the record for `codfilial = 1`

Comment: possibly, the `nf` table does not contain any rows with `codfilial = 10`?

Comment: You edited the question and changed your query. The current query will error if you run it (it would have errored before as well, but the condition was the glaring issue). You will need a `GROUP BY cod` to get through that error. There is nothing in your SQL that would cause your `cod=10` record to be dropped. You are either sharing a different query than you are running in your system or that record simply doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Add a group by clause and use left join instead of outer left join

```
select
   a.codfilial as cod,
   sum(nvl(b.sold, 0)) as total
from
  #tmpfilial          a
  left join #tmpnf b
  on a.codfilial = b.codfilial
group by  a.codfilial
```

[Result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kVw7.png)